# Is it possible to upload only 1 page from multiple pages report of Power BI to public website?

Tags: web, powerbi, power-bi-report-server

I hold power bi pro subscription. I need to upload only 1 page from the multiple pages of power BI report to my company website, how to solve this issue? need help !

i tried to find the solution but could not find any way to do it????

Answer (score 0):

You can hide all the other pages that you don't want to show.

Right-click on the page tab at the bottom of the canvas and select **Hide Page**. Note that there always needs at least one page unhidden.

[image]

Comment: how to do that?